# Considering N2 CMS but worried about performance. Is this justified?

Tags: asp.net, performance, .net-3.5, content-management-system, n2

Hy, does anyone worked with N2 Content Management System(http://www.codeplex.com/n2).
If yes, how does it perform, performance wise(under heavy load)?
It seems pretty simple and easy to use.

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this question at http://www.codeplex.com/n2/Thread/List.aspx

They might be able to tell you about performance limitations or bottlenecks.

Comment: I have first-hand statement from a Dutch company that built N2-based webshop with 15.000+ registered users. I guess that tells enough.

Answer (score 1):

http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/ and http://www.fancydressoutfitters.co.uk/ are n2cms based.

Read more on James Broome's blog http://jamesbroo.me/integrating-n2cms-into-who-can-help-me/

Answer (score 1):

We've built numerous sites in N2 and we love it.

Many of these sites have in excess of 20,000 users accessing on a daily basis.  We've also load tested up to 50,000 users with no problems.

It's running on fairly modest hardware - one web server, one db server.

With caching enabled it is extremly fast, as the database hardly gets hit!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it looked promising at first but quickly had issues actually deploying it to a Medium Trust host.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working locally prior to deployment to my host, and I think I may have cracked it - I ended up having to add a reference to the project assembly itself in the <n2><engine><assemblies> section. It was then able to find everything it was looking for, and so far, so MVC ;)

Comment: In medium trust mode, you must explicitly state one by one all assemblies you would like to use. In full trust mode (we all use on our development machines) all assemblies from bin folder are automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 high traffic web sites both using N2 CMS, its fast and reliable